# Texturing spacifc faces

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a complex object I am trying to texture with a real locations textures. I have the faces I want selected in edit mode and I UV unwrap them by projecting from bounds and it looks fine, like only the faces I selected are being unwrapped, but when I go to apply a new material, the material selects ALL of the faces, the ones I want, and the ones I don't want. What's the best way to get by this?

Comment: How many materials do you have on the mesh?

Comment: There are currently zero on the mesh. Each mesh I have will only have a total of 2 materials, I just can't figure out how to separate things properly.

Comment: When you add a first material it will be applied to all the mesh.

Comment: Oh sweat okay. So after the first material is on there, then I can go back and select the specific spaces and unwrap them?

Comment: You need to apply second material to those specific faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no materials applied to the mesh, first material that is created will be applied to whole mesh. There can not be part of mesh without a material. You have to create additional material for those specified faces.